# Getting Only one Screen while recording Agora

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I m getting only one screen while recording the screen

My Config
Start Recording

`https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/${config.agora.appID}/cloud_recording/resourceid/${resource}/mode/${mode}/start`,
{
cname: ',
uid: String(uid),
clientRequest: {
token,
recordingConfig: {
// subscribeVideoUids: ['#allstream#'],
// subscribeAudioUids: ['#allstream#'],
subscribeUidGroup: 0,
maxIdleTime: 30,
streamTypes: 2,
channelType: 0,
videoStreamType: 0,
audioProfile: 1,
transcodingConfig: {
height: 640,
width: 480,
bitrate: 400,
fps: 15,
mixedVideoLayout: 1,
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
}
},
recordingFileConfig: {
avFileType: ['hls', 'mp4']
},
storageConfig: {
vendor: 1,
region: 14,
bucket: '******',
accessKey: '*******',
secretKey: '******',
fileNamePrefix: ['media', 'recordings']
}
}
},
{ headers: { Authorization } }

Stop Recording

```
`http://api.agora.io/v1/apps/${config.agora.appID}/cloud_recording/resourceid/${resource}/sid/${sid}/mode/${mode}/stop`, {
      cname: eventId,
      uid: String(uid),
      clientRequest: {
        async_stop: false
      }
    },
    { headers: { Authorization } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "mix" as the value for your `mode` if you wish to have all the screens in the recording. If you are using "individual" as `mode` you will get multiple dumps for each users audio and video.